# QGIS 3.0.1 does not launch with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, qgis-3

I just performed an upgrade on my Lubuntu 16.04 and upgrade QGIS to 3.0.1. 
After the upgrade, however, qgis wouldn't launch, either from the command line or using the desktop icon. If I type

```
$ qgis
```

, it just returns silently without any error messages. The only thing that works is `qgis --help`.

```
$ ls -l $(which qgis)
```

shows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 411 Mar 24 10:34 /usr/bin/qgis
```

If I do `sudo apt-get install qgis`, I get:

```
qgis is already the newest version (1:3.0.1+24xenial-ubuntugis).
```

I have tried direct upgrade, removing qgis and then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpq* qgis* python-qgis* grass* --purge
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

, to no avail.

My apt source entries are:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis  xenial main
```

Has anyone experienced similar problems and know of a solution?

Comment: deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main works for me on 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the virtualbox guest additions (5.2.8) that's installed on the VM is the problem. If I fix the following three packages using `sudo apt-mark hold`, the problem disappears..

```
virtualbox-guest-dkms
virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-x11
```